# Error : the label [0] is not in the [index]

Tags: python, pandas

Halo,
Im a newbie using a python

First of all, i want to normalize my code. There is no problem when i normalized "datalatih" but there is accident when i tried to normalize called "datauji". I already make a different variable to normalize both of them.

Here is my data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("datalatihnodummy.csv", sep=';')
```

> > [image]

where my datalatih [:6] and datauji [6:]

Here is my sucessfuly code :

```
minperfeature = []
maxperfeature = []
for i in range(len(data.columns)):
    minperfeature.append(min(data[data.columns[i]]))
    maxperfeature.append(max(data[data.columns[i]]))
print(minperfeature)
print(maxperfeature)

datanormalisasi = datalatih

for i in range(len(datalatih.index)):
    for j in range(len(datalatih.columns)):
        datanormalisasi.loc[i, datalatih.columns[j]] =  (datanormalisasi.loc[i, datalatih.columns[j]] - minperfeature[j]) / (maxperfeature[j] - minperfeature[j])
datanormalisasi
```

> > [12, 17, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> >
> > [48, 135, 623, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
> >
> > 0
> >     0.638889
> >     0.652542
> >     0.409165
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1
> >     0.000000
> >     0.305085
> >     0.409165
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     2
> >     0.527778
> >     0.500000
> >     0.274959
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     3
> >     0.666667
> >     0.042373
> >     0.016367
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     4
> >     0.277778
> >     0.000000
> >     0.000000
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     5
> >     1.000000
> >     0.025424
> >     0.018003
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     1.0
> >     1.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0
> >     0.0

Here is my error code:

```
datanormalisasiUji = datauji
for i in range(len(datauji.index)):
    for j in range(len(datauji.columns)):
        datanormalisasiUji.loc[i, datauji.columns[j]] =  (datanormalisasiUji.loc[i, datauji.columns[j]] - minperfeature[j]) / (maxperfeature[j] - minperfeature[j])
datanormalisasiUji
```

the result was

> > 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'

Idk where is error show in my code, and i already solve my problem using different variables but still can't

Anyone know how solutions to solve it? Thanks before ^^

Comment: add the data please

Comment: i already update my data , thx makis

Comment: the loop seems to go outside the index. can you actually upload the file so that I can run the code and fix it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18xs8dKeIfLH31yVahFrxiyxdONOCYnjS, thx makis

Comment: which columns do you want to normalize?

Comment: Solved men, thx 4 ur help !!!

Comment: consider accepting and upvoting my answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want to normalize the columns: `[u'Umur', u'ALT/SGOT', u'AST/SGPT', u'Anoreksia', u'Mual']` **since they contain numerical values.**

**For the min-max normalization use this:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("datalatihnodummy.csv", sep=';')

df_new = df.iloc[:,1:6]
df_new.head(3)


   Umur  ALT/SGOT  AST/SGPT  Anoreksia  Mual
0    35        94       262          0     1
1    12        53       262          1     1
2    31        76       180          1     1


results = df_new - df_new.min() / (df_new.max() - df_new.min())
results

        Umur    ALT/SGOT   AST/SGPT  Anoreksia  Mual
0  34.666667   93.855932  261.98036        0.0   1.0
1  11.666667   52.855932  261.98036        1.0   1.0
2  30.666667   75.855932  179.98036        1.0   1.0
3  35.666667   21.855932   21.98036        0.0   1.0
4  21.666667   16.855932   11.98036        0.0   1.0
5  47.666667   19.855932   22.98036        1.0   0.0
6  17.666667  134.855932  622.98036        1.0   1.0
7  41.666667   67.855932   11.98036        0.0   0.0
```

Explanation: `Pandas` is smart and by typing: `df_new.min()`it estimates the min value of all columns.

```
df_new.min()

Umur         12
ALT/SGOT     17
AST/SGPT     12
Anoreksia     0
Mual          0
dtype: int64`
```